# How to get the list of define in c header file?

Tags: python, c++, c, header

I want to parse and get the list of definitions(#define) in c header file.

I know there are many python modules but I couldn't find parse pre-processors like "#if", "#undef".

If header file is as below:

```
#define ABC
#define DEF
#define CONDITION
#ifdef CONDITION
#undef DEF
#define HIJ
#endif
```

I want to get the list as below:

```
ABC, CONDITION, HIJ  // no DEF
```

Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844545/evaluate-all-macros-in-a-c-header-file

Answer (score 1):

I found out (but not using python).

> echo | g++ -dM -E my_header.h | sort > out.txt

including my_path

> echo | g++ -dM -E -I"my_path" my_header.h | sort > out.txt